# Check box on NSToolBar won't update?

Tags: cocoa, checkbox, interface-builder, nib

I have a Check Box on a tool bar, (NSToolbar) as in the image below.
It's action gets called and the sender.state toggles with each push, but on the tool bar the box never gets checked.

So the expected behaviour in terms of toggling, and the Action being called are all as you'd expect, it's just that the check box never redraws with the box checked.

I have tried setting sender.setNeedsDisplay=YES in the action, but that made no difference.

All the other controls on the tool bar work as expected.

Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Yup I can confirm that as well. Placing a checkbox in the toolbar does not update appearance. However, all other stateful controls (such as push-buttons or segmented controls) do, so, depending on your UI needs/preferences you may consider using them.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm running into the same exact issue.

Comment: No, sorry I didn't get anywhere with it. I think I will raise a bug report with Apple and see where that gets me.

Comment: I had a similar issue to this, and toggling the window for the toolbar to be Core Animation backed fixed it up. Worth a shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try embedding the checkbox in a NSBox which you configure to be borderless and transparent. worked for me --- button type should be checkbox

Answer (score 2):

Try embedding the checkbox in a `NSBox` which you configure to be borderless and transparent. As sadly so often for NSToolbarItems, this strategy works.